# Getting JS Error while clicking Copy Snippet to answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

To answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071719/the-confusion-about-the-way-how-iife-works) question, I hit "Copy Snippet To Answer" button. But nothing happened. So that I checked my console and found below error.

[image]

I did hard refresh and checked for the same, still getting the error in my console. Is that a bug or just issue on my browser only?

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [“copy snippet to answer” is no more working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384461/4642212).

Answer (score 4):

Should be working properly now. Snippets recently got a big ol' port to Typescript, during which a bunch of little changes were made to help improve clarity, performance, or both... Some of which caused unintended consequences.

This particular consequence should now be eliminated.

Comment: It seems to be working now.